# Initializing class member to emptyList in secondary constructor

Tags: kotlin

I'm very new to Kotlin and have to implement a data class TreeNode that resembles a generic tree of nodes. I'm trying to declare a secondary constructor that initializes the member children to be an empty list. Here's what I tried; but I'm not understanding the syntax quite well so not sure how to go about solving this.

```kotlin
data class TreeNode<T> (
    val value: T,
    val children: List<TreeNode<T>>,
) {

    constructor(value: T, children: emptyList<TreeNode<T>>): this(value){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting confused by where to put the arguments. If you know the list is empty, you don't need to take it as an argument.

```
constructor(value: T): this(value, emptyList()) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Silvio's answer, if you want to be able to take a list of children but default to not doing so:

```kotlin
data class TreeNode<T>(val value: T, val children: List<TreeNode<T>> = emptyList()) {}
```

See the section on default values in constructors in the Kotlin documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors

Comment: This would be the Kotlin way to do this, no need for a secondary constructor, when a default value can easily take its place. The question is an XY problem due to OP probably not knowing about default values.